# Open database reporsitories like Github for code

Tags: database, web-development, cloud-service

I just came to know that Github has now allowed private repository for free for developers. I am building a web application for which I need a database to connect. As I will be working on different devices throughout a day so I am looking for a database service which is just like Github, i.e.

- Allow me to have a private database connection & repository
- Allow me to connect, running queries on database server unlimited times or some big finite number. (as I will be developing an application)
- No cost involved (I am fine to get restricted when daily/weekly/monthly limit is reached)

Database size can not a concern for me as it is just for development, even 100 MB would be enough.

Though, I am looking for RDBMS but I am fine with DBMS as well.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly it is for one developer? Maybe https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/Can-we-have-free-private-repos/td-p/501 and https://github.blog/2019-01-07-new-year-new-github/ give some answers / possibilities / alternatives

Comment: @Albert Yes, I am the only developer working on a personal project. I am using git for my code versioning, I am looking something similar for my database as well so I don't have to worry about keeping my "latest" database copy to each system/device I use.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a free-tier instance on a cloud provider like Heroku,  and there you could install a Docker container with any RDBMS you like.

On Google Cloud Platform you can use FireBase  which is a powerful key-value store. No operating system configuration required. You can use Firebase for free (until some thresholds are exceeded).

I think there are even more options, but I don't want to recommend any particular companies here.